# react draft wysiwyg not displaying styles in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-draft-wysiwyg

so the html is like this:

```html
<p><span style="color: rgb(250,197,28);font-size: 96px;">Hello</span><span style="font-size: 96px;"> </span><span style="color: rgb(251,160,38);font-size: 96px;">World</span></p>
```

and my text editor creating with content is like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (content !== "") {
      console.log(content);
      const contentBlock = convertFromHTML(content);
      const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        contentBlock.contentBlocks
      );
      const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);

      setEditorState(editorState);
    }
  }, []);
```

so the inline styles are not being generated even though they are there and have correct syntext and should be generated but is there something wrong with this code or also I am using next js 12 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Simple passing the contentBlock will work. Use as below:

```
const contentBlock = convertFromHTML(content);    
const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock);
const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
```